# overloading error for C++ template function

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates

I am trying to do some practice with function templates as in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T max(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "max(10, 15) = " << max(10, 15) << endl;

    retun 0;

}
```

But I got the following errors. Could anybody recognize where the problem is?

```
..\src\main.cpp:59:40: error: call of overloaded 'max(int, int)' is   
ambiguous
cout << "max(10, 15) = " << max(10, 15) << endl;
                                    ^
..\src\main.cpp:16:3: note: candidate: 'T max(T, T) [with T = int]'
 T max(T a, T b)
^~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
             from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
             from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
             from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
             from ..\src\main.cpp:9:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:219:5: note:         
candidate: 'constexpr const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = int]'
max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
```

I am sorry I am new to templates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: max returns bool not T

Comment: Get rid of `using namespace std;` and you won't clash with [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: @michelson It most certainly does *not*.

Comment: Or stop naming your functions `max` or `min`, or anything else that sounds generic.  There is a good chance that using these often-used names as identifiers will lead to a name clash somewhere, whether it is in the standard headers, or some third-party code that isn't yours.

Answer (score 4):

Your usage of templates is correct, but the compiler complains that there already is a function called `max` with same arguments.

It's full name would be `std::max`, but because you wrote `using namespace std` its just `max` and compiler cannot know which function to call.

Solution is not to use `using`, see [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) .

Answer (score 2):

`using namespace std;` is the issue

Please stop using that, [see why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1870232)

The iostream header includes another header file that pulls `std::max`, giving a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help. My problem has been solved.